# static-link-runtime-shared-libraries in mxmlc

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxmlc

I use `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=false` for compiling my app and when I upload the new swf I periodically receive an Error #2046. If `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true` used it works OK. How do I handle with that?

I placed all the swz files into the same place as my app:

```
$ ls -l gae/static/swf/
total 4452
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  490561 2011-05-07 01:57 datavisualization_4.1.0.16076.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  291306 2011-05-07 01:57 datavisualization_4.1.0.16076.swz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid 1045994 2011-05-07 01:57 framework_4.1.0.16076.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  627104 2011-05-07 01:57 framework_4.1.0.16076.swz
-rw-r--r-- 1 soid soid  116596 2010-12-17 01:42 mapeditor.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  150731 2011-05-07 01:57 osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid   98079 2011-05-07 01:57 osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  207521 2011-05-07 01:57 rpc_4.1.0.16076.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  131927 2011-05-07 01:57 rpc_4.1.0.16076.swz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  503167 2011-05-07 01:57 spark_4.1.0.16076.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  319302 2011-05-07 01:57 spark_4.1.0.16076.swz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid   69851 2011-05-07 01:57 sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid   54538 2011-05-07 01:57 sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  263124 2011-05-07 01:57 textLayout_1.1.0.604.swf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soid soid  156998 2011-05-07 01:57 textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
```

I'm watching my server logs but I don't see any requests to these files. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and found this article in the adobe forums: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3501406

The author seems to have had similar inconsistent results as you and it had to do with loading RSL's - flex framework ones that you have listed in the question.

In his problem, IIS was blocking .swz files altogether.  After changing the IIS configuration, the problems went away.

Comment: It looks like this problem can be caused by many problems and it's hard to define what exactly. I don't use IIS.